# Analytics Snapshots for historical data

Tags: reporting

My intent is to show the number of Opportunities and the total Amount from Opportunities that are open at a given point in time for the past 2 years at my organization. I know this can be achieved going *forward* with the analytics snapshots, but I also need the data historically. I need Salesforce to generate snapshots of the past. Is this possible? How can I implement this as a report in the tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, this kind of historical data isn't available going into the past. Once those numbers change, unless their captured with an analytic snapshot, they're lost. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the custom object to hold your snapshot data, you should be able to insert new (older) records into your DB. You can generate the numbers you need by exporting opportunities with close and end-dates, and upload past data into your org and it will be treated exactly the same way.